# Getting Exception : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-rc

I am reaching to a page after clicking on a link.I have not clicking anything on that page yet. Still, As soon as the page loaded it throws an error:
**Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up**

```
List<WebElement> securityGroup = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[class='button-col']>a:nth-of-type(2)"));
System.out.println(securityGroup.size());

Thread.sleep(5000);

for(WebElement link:securityGroup) {
    String b= link.getAttribute("href");
    boolean a= b.contains(data0);

    if(a){
        System.out.println(b);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("before clicking link");
        link.click();   

        //After this new page opens and above error comes.**
    }else {
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }
}

Thread.sleep(5000);

Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='groupId']")));
System.out.println(sel.getOptions().toString());
sel.selectByValue("TEST");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the for loop.
You are finding the `securityGroup` which is a list and you are iterating through the list. In this `for` loop, you look for a condition and if yes you proceed to click on the link. But the issue here is that the list iteration is not complete and the for loop continues. But it wont find the `String b= link.getAttribute("href");` of the next iteration because you are on a new page.

Use a `break` to break the loop once the condition is satisfied.

```
if(a){
    System.out.println(b);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    System.out.println("before clicking link");
    link.click();   
    break;
}else {
    System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is not enough time to load the page and take the element:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='groupId']"))
```

try to do ImplicitlyWait after you init the driver

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and `Thread.sleep(5000);` is bad idea using with selenium, for waiting you have [selenium methods](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)

Comment: Hi, Did that but still no luck

Comment: in this case Sighil answer will be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `link` and redirected to another page the driver looses `securityGroup`. That's what causing the exception.

You need to relocate `securityGroup` each itreation

```
List<WebElement> securityGroup = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[class='button-col']>a:nth-of-type(2)"));
int size = securityGroup.size(); 

for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i) {
    securityGroup = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[class='button-col']>a:nth-of-type(2)"));
    WebElement link = securityGroup.get(i);

    String b = link.getAttribute("href");
    boolean a = b.contains(data0);

    if(a) {
        System.out.println(b);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        System.out.println("before clicking link");
        link.click();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("No match found");
    }
}
```